# Why cannot I create extension to BigDecimal in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

I am trying to create an extension as a property and I experimented with an extension function as well, below an example for `BigDecimal`:

```
val BigDecimal.HUNDRED: BigDecimal
    get() = TEN.multiply(TEN)

fun BigDecimal.HUNDRED_ONE(): BigDecimal {
    return TEN.multiply(TEN)
}
```

It seems that Kotlin recognizes neither `HUNDRED` nor `HUNDRED_ONE()`. I am using Kotlin version `1.5.21`.

Am I doing anything wrong on Kotlin version `1.5.21` that doesn't work correctly?

I have used this functionality before for lists. For instance:

```
fun <T> toList(list: List<T>?): List<T> {
    return list ?: listOf()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you wanted to use it like this:

```kotlin
val value = BigDecimal.HUNDRED
```

As far as I know, this is not possible in Kotlin right now. Extensions work on instances, so they're more like instance members, not static members. With your above code this will work: `BigDecimal(0).HUNDRED`.

I believe there is only one situation when it is possible to provide "static" extensions. If class has a companion (so it is Kotlin class) then we can add extensions to this companion. But this is not at all applicable to `BigDecimal` or any other Java class.

Comment: [Relevant YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968)